# Enabling and disabling buttons in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

For a given simple audio app with a few buttons:

[image]

The button references inside `ViewController` is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var recordAudioButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playAudioButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var processAudioButton: UIButton!
```

But where are those button names and references inside the xcode gui? Notice below that the `Allow Recording` button is highlighted: but there is no mention of `recordAudioButton` as a button name:

[image]

I want to modify the enabling/disabling logic of a different button that does not have a reference yet.. but can not see how/where to do that . The dialog does not show a way to view/change the button references.  So where is the place to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### See in Referencing Outlets Section for each button.

[image]

You can set disable after buttons setup

```
@IBOutlet weak var recordAudioButton: UIButton! {
    didSet { recordAudioButton.isEnabled = false }
}
@IBOutlet weak var playAudioButton: UIButton! {
    didSet { playAudioButton.isEnabled = false }
}
@IBOutlet weak var processAudioButton: UIButton! {
    didSet { processAudioButton.isEnabled = false }
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad check for permission

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {                         
        self.recordAudioButton.isEnabled = allowed
        self.playAudioButton.isEnabled = allowed
        self.processAudioButton.isEnabled = allowed
    }
}
```

Then your code

```
@IBAction func askForPermissions() {
    recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
        try recordingSession.setActive(true)
        recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
            // UI related work has to be executed on main thread(queue)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {                         
                self.recordAudioButton.isEnabled = allowed
                self.playAudioButton.isEnabled = allowed
                self.processAudioButton.isEnabled = allowed
            }
        }
    } catch let error {
        presentError(withMessage: error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was discovering this and writing up an answer in parallel to yours here. Just upvoted yours.

Answer (score 1):

You just defined the `button` as an `outlet`. So it does not appear on the `Touch Up Inside`, it appears at outlets area. But you connect your `other button` to an `action function`, this `button` appears on the `Touch Up Inside`.

Comment: What is the process to connect the `other button`  to an `action function` ?

Comment: You connected your button to func askForPermissions func. This is the action function. Your button which you connect this function appears at Touch Up Inside.

Comment: I found a reference and then fiddled a bit to discover how to do it: will add notes on it

Comment: Okay, please let me know the results.

Comment: Added an answer that did reference yours.

Answer (score 0):

Given the starting point / hint from @Picode here is what I was missing to get a new `UIButton` reference.   A `Medium` article helped pave the way  https://medium.com/@GanChau/outlet-vs-action-connections-in-xcode-b5331fb233a1  . In particular we need to have both an `Editor` and the `Visual Designer` showing:

[image]

So on *my* project now I control-clicked on the new button `Run DSP` and the context menu shows up:

[image]

Now select `New Referencing Outlet` and connect it to the `ViewController` code:

[image]

I typed in `dspJsButton` for the `Name`  and we get the following code generated:

```
     @IBOutlet weak var dspJsButton: UIButton!
```

Comment: I am glad it works :) Please accept my answer if it was helped you.